# Install Realtek rtl8822be (Asus ROG B450-I) Motherboard WiFi Driver

Tags: debian, drivers, firmware

I am trying to get the WiFi working on my Asus ROG B450-I motherboard. I am running OpenMediaVault (5.5.6-1) which is built on Debian, but I seem to be failing at every attempt.

I know I have the correct device as if I run *lspci* I get the following:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] (rev a1)
```

Can see it there at 04:00.0.

The device just does not appear in the networking options.
[image]

I've also installed *firmware-realtek (20190717-2-bpo10+1)* via apt-get and it says installed, I've rebooted and appears to have made no difference.

Also if I run *lshw -class network* I can see it listed as unclaimed:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f5500000-f550ffff
```

Pretty much at a loss as to how to get this to go, any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

Did as per @Artem S. Tashkinov below and then ran:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

Then the output of *dmesg* is available here: https://jpst.it/2fKES

Answer (score 0):

"Unclaimed" means you do **not** have a kernel module/driver to run this device.

You need to download and install https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de

Start with:

```bsh
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)  build-essential
```

Comment: Done that, but lshw still showing it as "Unclaimed".

Comment: Please post the tail of `dmesg` output after you `modprobe` the driver (no idea how it's called). Make sure you've actually `modeprobe`'d it because compiling alone might not be enough.

Comment: I've posted an update showing what I did with a link to dmesg output

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've actually modprobed the driver (`dmesg` is empty) or it doesn't yet support your hardware in which case I've no idea what to do.

Comment: Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by doing the following:

Found this github page:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Followed the instructions in the read-me.

Ensured checked for blacklisting, and did the modprobe after a reboot

```
sudo modprobe rtw_8722be
```

This then showed the network device as *disabled*

Ran the command

```
ip link set dev wlp4s0 up
```

*wlsp4s0* was the name of my interface

All I then needed to do was configure it in the gui as the device finally displayed.